# Spring Data MongoDB Connection Logging

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, log4j2, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a way of checking if a mongo connection has been successfully opened during app deployment?

I am not having any connection input returned on logs.

I have this on my log4j properties.

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.mongodb=TRACE
```

I only get this on my trace related to mongo.

```
DEBUG [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] (MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:122) - Analyzing class class com.marcoremane.spring.entity.Client for index information.
```

I am doing XML based configurations

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017">
    <mongo:client-options connect-timeout="1000"/>
</mongo:mongo-client>

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="minib" mongo-ref="mongoClient"/>

<mongo:template db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
```

Comment: Try to ping the IP and port

Answer (score 0):

Try switching on Log4j2 internal logging:

```
<Configuration status="trace">
```

Log4j2 internal logging statements will be printed to the console. This should include success or failure of database connectivity.